# skip html tags when using preg_replace

Tags: php, html, tags, strip

```
   <?php
   $str = '<html><b>string</b></html>';
    $code = "+";

    $lol = preg_replace('~.~', "\\0$code", $str);
    echo $lol;
```

output looks like that

```
<+h+t+m+l+>+<+b+>+s+t+r+i+n+g+<+/+b+>+<+/+h+t+m+l+>+
```

html tags effected ! i need only to effect the text

so output must look like this

```
<html><b>s+t+r+i+n+g+</b></html>
```

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)